# ddplyr put char variable in old data frame, into new data frame based on condition

Tags: r, char, plyr

I am a beginner. I've looked at around 10 ddplyr related questions, but mostly I don't understand them. I am unable to transfer a character variable from old data frame into new data frame based on my condition. Such that, Even though I have only one primary condition, I had to make separate conditions for each numeric variable to get it into the new df. Below code is working for me, except for the character variable.

```
  Newdata<-ddply(Olddata, ~ ID,summarize, Num1= min(Num1),Num2=max(Num2),
               Num3=min(Num3),Num4=min(Num4))
```

Data

[image]

My primary condition is Num1= min(Num1), if I could get Num3,4 and char based on that, it would be great. And i'll add another condition Num2=max(Num2). Thank you.

Sorry I can't embed images right now because of points issue.And I can't post more than 2, so I'm only posting the expected. For my current output, you can just imagine below expected output to be the without the last column.
I simply want to include the final character variable from my old data, and I'm unable to do it:
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnL5L.png)

Comment: It is not clear from the description.  Please show the expected output

Comment: @akrun I can't embed images because of no reputation, but you can see the expected output by clicking the link. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to do this.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(Olddata)`), grouped by 'ID', specify the columns to get the `min` in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Data.table to get the `min` (`lapply(.SD, min)`), concatenate (`c`) with the `max` of 'Num2' and set the column order (`setcolorder`) as that of 'Olddata'

```
library(data.table)
setcolorder(setDT(Olddata)[, c(Num2 = max(Num2), lapply(.SD, min)), 
   .SDcols = setdiff(names(Olddata), c("Num2", "ID")), by = ID], names(Olddata))[]
#   ID   Num1     Num2 Num3 Num4   Char
#1:  1 787979   565655   12  100 George
#2:  2  13203 11213232   14  100   Dean
```

#### data

```
 Olddata <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(1, 2), each = 2), Num1 = c(4545466, 787979, 13203, 444444),
     Num2 = c(565655, 74545, 22.565, 11213232), Num3 = c(12, 13, 14, 15), 
     Num4  = 100, Char = c("George", "Michael", "Dean", "Sam"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: For some reason it is giving me an error:

Error in gmax(Num2) : object 'Num2' not found

Comment: @Poppinyoshi  Are you using the data in my post?  Which version of `data.table` you have installed?/  I am using `data.table_1.10.4`

Comment: It was 1.9 , I upgraded and it works well! thank you